# 言わば、言うなれば、言うならば and 言ってみれば

Tags: grammar, words, expressions

Do all the expressions 言わば、言うなれば、言うならば and 言ってみれば mean "so to speak" and can be used interchangeably or is there any difference between them?

I can't get very well the differences in nuances between these expressions (in case there are).

Besides, is there any other similar expression to these previous ones meaning "so to speak"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little difference, and they are all interchangeable. Although they are all stiff and formal phrases, I feel that 言わば and 言ってみれば are relatively more casual, while 言うなれば is only used in serious essays and such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. :)